# Refresh Windows CE - Taskbar

Tags: c#, refresh, c#-2.0, windows-ce

Is there a possibility to refresh the Taskbar in Windows CE by C#?

In my software I kill some processes by OpenNETCF.ToolHelp.ProcessEntry.Kill()
This works fine, the Icon is removed from the taskbar, but the space for the icon is still left. After some tests I killed about 20 processes, and now it pushed out the start-button from the taskbar.

The empty space is removed by clicking on it.

How can I refresh the taskbar from my C#-program?

EDIT: I'm currently working on CE 4.2

Comment: You're trying to solve the problem the wrong way round. Why are you killing all these processes in the first place?

Comment: I'm disconnecting my gprs-connection by rasmanager, but the process is still running, although there isn't any connection left.

So I have to kill the rnaapp-process to close the window

This works fine, but the space of the icon won't be removed

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the handle to the taskbar window P/Invoking FindWindow, look for "HHTaskBar" as class name.  Then invalidate the window.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion by `Damon8or`, here is sample code that does what you need:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int nMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

public static void RefreshTrayArea()
{
    // The client rectangle can be determined using "GetClientRect" (from coredll.dll) but
    // does require the taskbar to be visible. The values used in the loop below were
    // determined empirically.
    IntPtr hTrayWnd = FindWindow("HHTaskBar", null);
    if (hTrayWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        int nStartX = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2);
        int nStopX = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        int nStartY = 0;
        int nStopY = 26;    // From experimentation...
        for (int nX = nStartX; nX < nStopX; nX += 10)
            for (int nY = nStartY; nY < nStopY; nY += 5)
                SendMessage(hTrayWnd,
                    WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)((nY << 16) + nX));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I hope this helps someone else!

But as this question is from 2011 I don't need an answer anymore :)